# How to use defined function with xargs

Tags: bash, xargs, function

This is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

showword() {
  echo $1
}

echo This is a sample message | xargs -d' ' -t -n1 -P2 showword
```

So I have a function `showword` which echoes whatever string you pass as a parameter to the function.

Then I have `xargs` trying to call the function and pass one word at a time to the function, and run 2 copies of the function in parallel. The thing that is not working is `xargs` doesn't recognize the function. How can I achieve what I am trying to do, how can I make xargs work with the function `showword`?

Comment: Also discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003418/calling-shell-functions-with-xargs

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try exporting the function, then calling it in a subshell:

```
showword() {
  echo $1
}

export -f showword
echo This is a sample message | xargs -d' ' -t -n1 -P2 bash -c 'showword "$@"' _
```

This causes `xargs` to execute

```
bash -c 'showword "$@"' _ This
bash -c 'showword "$@"' _ is
bash -c 'showword "$@"' _ a
            ︙
```

The arguments passed to the `bash` command are, well,
passed into the bash  environment, but starting from 0. 
So, inside the function,

- `$0` is “`_`” and `$1` is “`This`”
- `$0` is “`_`” and `$1` is “`is`”
- `$0` is “`_`” and `$1` is “`a`”
- ︙

See [Bash -c with positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152391/80216).

Note that `export -f` works only in Bash,
and `-Pn` (`--max-procs=max-procs`)
works only in GNU `xargs`.

Comment: One more question, why is the trailing _ required? Is it to stop xargs from processing anything else?

Comment: @FazleA.: read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152391/bash-c-with-positional-parameters

Comment: I am getting "export: Illegal option -f" when I do export -f

Comment: @SagarChamling export -f works in bash only

Comment: @cuonglm this does invoke a new `bash` process for every `xargs` item, right?

Comment: @NarūnasK No, for each xargs invocation.

Comment: Why does this work? Or, more specifically, why is the bash -c subshell needed (why can't xargs just detect and use the function just defined in the same shell process)?

Comment: @Magnus because `xargs` run the command in new process, not with the original one. That's why you need `export f` to make the function visible in sub-shells.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding an alternative solution using `parallel` which I have started using in place of `xargs`. The task is much easier with `parallel`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

showword() {
  echo $1
}
export -f showword

parallel -j2 showword {} ::: This is a sample message
```

- `-j2` makes sure 2 copies of the function is run in parallel
- `:::` anything after this is passed as separate arguments to `parallel`, separation is whitespace
- `{}` is replaced by the argument passed into `parallel` and fed into the `showword` function

---

*If you are using zsh shell this solution will not work since zsh does not have any feature to export functions. You will need something like this:*

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

showword() {
  echo $1
}

# add the following to your .zshrc if you want env_parallel in your shell permanently
source /usr/bin/env_parallel.zsh

env_parallel -j2 --env showword showword {} ::: This is a sample message
```

Comment: Where does `/usr/bin/env_parallel.zsh` come from? I don't have it on my system...

Comment: @friederbluemle On Ubuntu, if I run the command `dpkg -S /usr/bin/env_parallel.zsh`, it says the file `/usr/bin/env_parallel.zsh` comes from the package `parallel`

Answer (score 0):

Let we have a function which takes argument and does anything (mine prints it two times)

```shellsession
$ twice() { echo $1$1 }

$ twice "hello"
hellohello
```

It doesn't work with pipe as it doesn't read any input

```shellsession
$ echo "hello" | twice
<nothing>
```

We can simply fix this by reading input to temp variable

```shellsession
$ echo "hello" | read s; twice $s
hellohello
```

Or with helper function

```shellsession
$ call() { read s; $1 $s }

$ echo "hello" | call twice
hellohello
```