# What's the `name` argument to `sh -c` for?

Tags: shell, debian, freebsd, arguments

Taken from [FreeBSD's man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh) on sh (because its the most convenient online, target platform is Debian if it matters):

```
SH(1)           FreeBSD General Commands Manual          SH(1)

NAME
     sh -- command interpreter (shell)

SYNOPSIS
     sh [-/+abCEefhIimnPpTuVvx] [-/+o longname] [script [arg ...]]
     sh [-/+abCEefhIimnPpTuVvx] [-/+o longname] -c string [name [arg ...]]
     sh [-/+abCEefhIimnPpTuVvx] [-/+o longname] -s [arg ...]
...
```

I'm particularly interested in the use case of:

```
sh [-/+abCEefhIimnPpTuVvx] [-/+o longname] -c string [name [arg ...]]
```

#### Example:

```
# Normal:
myscript hello world
myscript hello world >/var/log/myscript.combined 2>&1

# Constrained:
#  - Arguments 'hello' and 'world' are suffixed by calling program.
myscript >/var/log/myscript.combined 2>&1 hello world

# Constrained Further:
#  - Wrapped in `sh` to catch system messages, like Segmentation Fault

sh -c 'myscript $@' _ >/var/log/myscript.combined 2>&1 hello world
```

I noticed that the first argument was not passed to `myscript`, and the documentation alludes to a `name` parameter, that I didn't see a doc section on. In my example I have added ad `_` in place of the name argument, but:

#### What should I fill for `name`?

Answer (score 7):

The form:

```
sh -c '...' name arg1 arg2 ...
```

is called inline-script, often seen in combination with `find ... -exec sh -c '...' find-sh {} +`. Inside inline-script, `$0` will be set to `name`, and the rest of arguments was populated to `$@`.

In general, you should set it to something meaningful, because it will be used for instance showing error messages:

```
sh -c 'echo "${1?}"' foo
foo: 1: foo: 1: parameter not set
```

But you can set `name` to any word you like, to indicate the name of inline-script:

```
sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$0"' custom-sh 1 2 3
custom-sh
```

This behavior is defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_04).

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152391/231113 for further details on the `command_name` argument

Answer (score 5):

Man page in Linux was detailed a bit.

> sh -c [-aCefnuvxIimqVEb] [+aCefnuvxIimqVEb] [-o option_name] [+o
>   option_name] command_string [command_name [argument ...]]
>
> **-c**               Read commands from the command_string operand
>   instead of from the standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set
>   from the                         command_name operand and the
>   positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining argument
>   operands.
>
> **command_name** A string assigned to special parameter 0 when executing
>   the commands in command_string. If command_name is not specified,
>   special parameter 0 shall be set to the value of the first argument
>   passed to sh from its parent (for example, argv[0] for a C program),
>   which is normally a pathname used to execute the sh utility.

Comment: Hmmk, I tested with a php script and a python script, both of which seem to populate their own argv[0] dynamically. So perhaps this argument doesn't apply to my use case. I would like to know if it gets used anywhere like by the kernel as metadata to the process.