# How can I store a string literal to a variable with no substitution or interpretation?

Tags: shell, variable

To flatten a directory structure, I can do this:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "./`basename "{}"`"'  \;
```

I want to store the following in my profile as $FLATTEN

```
-exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "./`basename "{}"`"'  \;
```

so that later I can just execute `find . $FLATTEN`

I'm having trouble storing the variable because it gets interpreted too early.  I want it to be stored as a string literal and interpreted only in usage on the shell, not when sourced.

Comment: See [But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408#286350)

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If using GNU `mv`, you should rather do:

```
find . -type f -exec mv -t . {} +
```

With other `mv`s:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'exec mv "$@" .' sh {} +
```

You should never embed `{}` in the `sh` code. That's a command injection vulnerability as the names of the files are interpreted as shell code (try with a file called `` `reboot` `` for instance).

Good point for quoting the command substitution, but because you used the archaic form (`` `...` `` as opposed to `$(...)`), you'd need to escape the inner double quotes or [it won't work in `sh` implementations based on the Bourne shell or AT&T ksh](/a/387289) (where `` "`basename "foo bar"`" `` would actually be treated as `` "`basename " `` (with an unmatched `` ` `` which is accepted in those shells) concatenated with `foo` and then `` bar"`" ``).

Also, when you do:

```
mv foo/bar bar
```

If `bar` actually existed and was a directory, that would actually be a `mv foo/bar bar/bar`. `mv -t . foo/bar` or `mv foo/bar .` don't have that issue.

Now, to store those several arguments (`-exec`, `sh`, `-c`, `exec mv "$@" .`, `sh`, `{}`, `+`) into a variable, you'd need an array variable. Shells supporting arrays are `(t)csh`, `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `rc`, `es`, `yash`, `fish`.

And to be able to use that variable as just `$FLATTEN` (as opposed to `"${FLATTEN[@]}"` in ksh/bash/yash or `$FLATTEN:q` in `(t)csh`), you'd need a shell with a sane array implementation: `rc`, `es` or `fish`. Also `zsh` here as it happens none of those arguments is empty.

In `rc`/`es`/`zsh`:

```
FLATTEN=(-exec sh -c 'exec mv "$@" .' sh '{}' +)
```

In `fish`:

```
set FLATTEN -exec sh -c 'exec mv "$@" .' sh '{}' +
```

Then you can use:

```
find . -type f $FLATTEN
```

Comment: why is `sh` repeated in your "other `mv`s" section?

Comment: @haventchecked The second sh is what goes into the inline script's `$0` (what gives a name to that inline script)

Comment: thank you, that was enough to find another source https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226898/118708

I really like your answer and appreciate you pointing out the defects in my approach.  I didn't know what I didn't know about it yet.

Comment: @haventchecked, you're welcome. See edit for another issue in your code I forgot to  mention in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to use a shell function for this, and to get the `-exec` right (don't put `{}` in a subshell):

```
flatten () {
     ( cd "${1:-.}" && 
       find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for n; do test -e "${n##*/}" || mv "$n" "${n##*/}"; done' sh {} + )
}
```

This also doesn't need to call the external utility `basename` and will not try to overwrite already existing things.

You would use this by just typing `flatten` and it will act on the current directory.  Giving it a directory name will make it act on that (copying all files under that directory to the top of that directory).

Answer (score 3):

How about a function?

```
flatten(){
  find "$@" -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "${0##*/}"' {} \;
}
```

Usage:

```
> flatten .
```

---

If you use `zsh`, there's the `-g` option of `alias` for that. It lets you define an alias which is inserted globally, not just at the command name.

Comment: [Looping over find’s output is bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/23408).

Comment: @Scott You're right, I reverted it – thanks for the feedback!

Comment: This will copy all files in the given directory (or under) to the _current_ directory. This may be unexpected. I dunno.

Comment: @Kusalananda I wondered that myself, but OP clearly wants it this way. Is it a bug? Is it a feature?

Comment: @dessert Note that the OP is defaulting to the current directory, always. To move all files below `path/dir` into `path/dir` you would have to `cd` there first and then move to the current directory, alternatively pass the `path/dir` as an argument to the `sh -c` shell and use it in the to augment the destination path.

Answer (score 3):

A function is probably the best way. Otherwise you need an array or `eval`:

```
find_array=(-exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "./`basename "{}"`"'  \;)
find . "${find_array[@]}"
```

or

```
FLATTEN="-exec sh -c 'mv \"{}\" \"./`basename \"{}\"`\"'  \;"
eval find . $FLATTEN
```