# Getting error when calling shell script ONLY with "sh -c" : "unexpected operator"

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, shell

I have the following script:

```bsh
installRequiredFiles=$1

install_with_pkg()
{
    arg1=$1
        echo $arg1
    echo "[+] Running update: $arg1 update."
}

if [ $installRequiredFiles = "true" ]; then
    if [ -x "$(command -v apt)" ]; then
          install_with_pkg "apt"
        elif [ -x "$(command -v yum)" ]; then
          install_with_pkg "yum"
        elif [ -x "$(command -v apk)" ]; then
          install_with_pkg "apk"
        else
          echo "[!] Can't install files."
    fi
fi
```

When I run it straight forward it works fine:

```bsh
root@ubuntu:/# ./myscript.sh "true"
apt
[+] Running update: apt update.
Printing installRequiredFiles: true
Printing arg1: apt
```

But when I am using `sh -c` I am getting the following error:

```bsh
root@ubuntu:/# sh -c ./myscript.sh "true"
./c.sh: 11: [: =: unexpected operator
Printing installRequiredFiles:
Printing arg1:
```

I want to be able to run it correctly with `sh -c` and I want it to support `sh` and `bash` which currently does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not what the `-c` option is for. You normally don't give it a file, you give it shell commands. It is meant for doing things like this:

```
$ sh -c 'echo hello'
hello
```

Now that you gave it a file, it is trying to read it and execute the commands found in it, but the argument isn't passed to the script (`myscript.sh`), the argument is only given to the `sh` command itself as you can see if you simply print the arguments:

```
$ cat script.sh
echo "ARGS: $@"

$ sh ./script.sh true
ARGS: true
$ sh -c ./script.sh true
ARGS:
```

All you need to do is to not use `-c` and it will work as expected:

```
sh ./myscript.sh "true"
```

Or, if you absolutely must use `-c` for some reason, pass the script *and* the argument for the script as a single, quoted argument to `sh`:

```
sh -c './myscript.sh "true"'
```

Comment: Also, for -c invocations, the first argument becomes `$0`: `sh -c 'echo $0; echo $1' foo bar`

Comment: Note that the last command will end up executing the script with a shell that possibly depends on what shell implements the `sh` shell (since the script lacks `#!`-line). It's a bit unclear, but addressed by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223

Comment: Another issue they have is the unquoted `$installRequiredFiles` in the test. If it was quoted, there would be no error, the test would be just false. Not that it might make it easier to figure out what's wrong, but [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) applies here, too...

Answer (score 3):

The error that you get is from the `dash` shell (the shell used for implementing `/bin/sh` on your system).  It is due to `$installRequiredFiles` being

1. an empty string, and
2. used unquoted.

Since the variable is empty, using it unquoted removes it completely from the command, which means that the line

```bsh
if [ $installRequiredFiles = "true" ]; then
```

would be interpreted as

```bsh
if [ = "true" ]; then
```

which in turn is an error in the usage of the `[` command; it sees the operator `=` when no operator was expected.

So, why is `$installRequiredFiles` (and `$1`), empty?

The command

```bsh
sh -c ./myscript.sh "true"
```

runs the command `./myscript.sh` with `$0` set to the string `true` in the script. The value in `$0` is usually the name of the script or of the shell, and the value is most commonly used in diagnostic messages (e.g. in error messages that the shell produces).

If you had used

```bsh
sh -c ./myscript.sh sh "true"
```

instead, then `$1` would have been set to `test` as expected, and `$0` would have been set to `sh` (which is customary for in-line `sh -c` scripts). In both cases, the script would have been executed by whatever shell executes scripts with no `#!`-line. What shell ends up running the script is possibly depending on the `sh` shell on your machine, and it may not be `sh` or `bash`. See, e.g., [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223).

You likely want to add a `#!`-line in your script pointing to `/bin/sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# ... rest of script here ...
# ... just remember to quote all expansions ...
```

That means you'll be able to run your script like so:

```bsh
$ ./myscript.sh test
```

or, with the *equivalent*

```bsh
$ sh -c './myscript.sh "test"'
```

or,

```bsh
$ sh -c './myscript.sh "$@"' sh test
```

Note that in the last two of these cases, it's not the `sh -c` shell that is executing the script, but whatever shell the `#!`-line in the script refers to, just as if you ran `./myscript.sh "test"` directly. The difference compared to before adding the `#!`-line is that you now know for certain that this is `/bin/sh` and not some other shell.

The script uses only POSIX shell syntax, which means it would be executable by `/bin/sh`, regardless of what shell is used to implement `/bin/sh` on any given system. If `/bin/sh` is `bash`, `ksh` or `dash` or some other more exotic shell does not matter, the user should not need to worry about running the script with the correct interpreter.

Related to various parts of this answer:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [What's the `name` argument to `sh -c` for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226897)
- [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223)

Comment: To clarify: running `sh -c ./myscript.sh sh "true"` will set `$1` to "true" while executing the *command* `./myscript.sh`, but not while running the *script* `./myscript.sh`. Since that command runs the script without passing any arguments, the arg list within the script will be empty. That's why `sh -c './myscript.sh "$@"'` is needed to pass the arguments on to the script.