# Can the command within for-loop affect the iterations?

Tags: bash

In Bash,

1. the syntax of the C-like for-loop is:

   ```
   for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do commands ; done
   ```

   Can the execution of `commands` affect the evaluations of the three
   arithmetic expressions `expr1`, `expr2`, and/or `expr3`, and
   therefore change the iterations (e.g. the number of iterations)?

   Or are the iterations (e.g. the number of iterations) unaffected by
   execution of `commands` in each iteration?
2. The other syntax of the for command is:

   ```
   for name [ [in [words ...] ] ; ] do commands; done
   ```

   Can execution of `commands` in each iteration affect the iterations (e.g. the number of iterations)?

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
$ bash -c 'for ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo $i; ((i++)); done'
0
2
4
6
8
```

In the `for ((expr1; expr2; expr3)` form, `expr2` (and `expr3`, if `expr2` didn't fail) are evaluated each time the loop is run. With the other form, bash starts the loop after `words` have been expanded (that includes performing command substitution, globbing, etc.). So you can't affect the possible values of the iteration variable (`name`) once the loop starts. You can, of course:

```
$ bash -c 'for i; do echo $i; break; done' _ a b c
a
```

Comment: Thanks. How about the same questions for the other syntax of for-loop?

Comment: @Tim see update

Comment: what does `_` mean in `bash -c 'for i; do echo $i; break; done' _ a b c`?

Comment: `_` is `$0` in this case. Since `for i` only loops from the first argument, I used `_` as placeholder. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152391/70524