# Using the "$@" special args in a new bash command (bash -c)

Tags: bash, arguments

I am trying to run a `bash -c` command relying on the parent bash scripts arguments via `"$@"`

When running a normal command, I use `"$@"` and bash does the expand magic for each arg.

```
printf '[%s] [%s]\n' "$@"
```

```
$ ./script one "t w o"
[one] [t w o]
```

My first naive attempt at escaping falls over in an odd way with the `$@` quotes as the parent bash appears to the "end" the current argument.

```
bash -c "printf '%s %s\n' \"$@\""
```

```
$ ./script one "t w o"
t w o": -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
t w o": -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

From there `"$@"` kind of defies my regular escaping tricks as nothing is really quoted, I'm guessing bash deals with the expansion at a lower `exec` level.

How do I use the `"$@"` script arguments in a `bash -c` one liner?

Comment: injecting `quoted_args=$(printf "'%s' " "$@")` works for non ' cases but that seems like the wrong solution...

Comment: Pass on the arguments as arguments? `bash -c 'printf "%s %s\n" "$@"' arg-zero "$@"`?

Comment: yep, i'd jumped it due to the arg-zero missing issue. Do you know the reason for that?

Comment: The first argument becomes `$0`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152391/70524

Comment: Awesome, always quick with the foot gun. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid escaping, use `"$@"` as normal and pass `"$@"` to the parent `bash -c` including a dummy argument for `$0`.

```
bash -c 'printf "[%s] [%s]\n" "$@"' this-is-bash-dollar-zero "$@"
```

```
$ ./script one "t w o"
[one] [t w o]
```

Comment: In many cases [`--` is special](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618), but not here.`bash` stops detecting options after the option-argument to `-c`. Whatever follows becomes `$0`, `$1`, etc. With `--` there `bash -c` simply takes *this string* as `$0`. It makes sense to place a meaningful string there because `$0` is used in error messages.(try `bash -c if --` vs `bash -c if my-special-purpose-bash`).

Comment: IOW, you should use `bash -c 'inline script' helpful-name-for-my-inline-script arg1 arg2...` or just `bash -c 'inline script' bash arg1 arg2...`, not `bash -c 'inline script' -- arg1 arg2...` as `--` is a very confusing name for your *inline script*.

Comment: oic, I assumed it was the usual `--`