# Using rsync copying all certain files into one single folder - no find command

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

although there are many rsync examples out there, my question:
Is there a rsync only command line which copies certain file types (like. .mp3) into one single folder !without using any find command! and !without any! recreation of dir structure on dest folder? (Even if this would result in a huge directory?)

Comment: what's wrong with simply using `find` for this?

Comment: Are source and destination on the same system? Or are you suggesting `rsync` because the copy is between two different machines?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get `rsync` to copy files recursively from a directory hierarchy into a single flat directory.  This is easiest done using `find`:

```bash
find source-dir -name '*.mp3' -type f -exec cp {} dest-dir/ \;
```

The above looks in `source-dir` for any regular file whose name ends in `.mp3`, and copies it to `dest-dir` (name collisions are not handled).

With GNU tools, this can be made more efficient so that `cp` is called as few times as possible:

```bash
find source-dir -name '*.mp3' -type f -exec cp -t dest-dir/ {} +
```

There's nothing stopping you from calling `rsync` in place of `cp`, of course:

```bash
find source-dir -name '*.mp3' -type f -exec rsync -a {} dest-dir/ \;
```

Or, more efficiently,

```bash
find source-dir -name '*.mp3' -type f -exec sh -c 'rsync -a "$@" dest-dir/' sh {} +
```

If you can guarantee that you have less than a few thousand files and if you have a shell that supports the `**` filename globbing pattern (as with `shopt -s globstar` in `bash`):

```bash
rsync -a --no-r source-dir/**/*.mp3 dest-dir/
```

This does, however, not let you check the file type of the matched pathnames, and it would only match non-hidden names.  In the `zsh` shell, you could use `source-dir/**/*.mp3(.D)` to only select (possibly hidden) regular files. In the `bash` shell, you would need to iterate over the matching pathnames and test each with the `-f` test.  You must also set the `dotglob` shell option to match hidden names.

Comment: Can you explain `-exec sh -c 'rsync -a "$@" dest-dir/' sh {} +`?  Why does `sh` occur twice?

Comment: @gerrit This should hopefully answer that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152391/bash-c-with-positional-parameters