# Explanation of sh-c

Tags: shell, find

I am going through ,this answer here
[Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

I am not able to understand, how below piece of code works

```
sh -c 'echo "hello $1" ' somestring works
```

How does that work,if i remove `somestring` ,it doesn't even work..

I tried searching with keywords like `sh -c examples`,but its not yielding any results

Comment: [What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

Comment: In your case, `somestring` will be the name of the script. Try using: `sh -c 'echo -e "Filename: $0\nhello $1" ' `. The first argument after sh -c '...' it's the name of the script and the following values are the parameters passed to that script.
You should check the link that @KamilMaciorowski provided.

Comment: Thank you both for your time and help

Comment: See [Bash -c with positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152391/170373)